# xibファイルのViewを画面サイズに合わせるには

Tags: ios, xib

InterfaceBuilderでxibファイルを「iphone-4inch」(width:320px,height:568px)でUIViewを作りました。そのViewをViewControllerでaddSubViewするのですが、どの端末でシミュレートしても4インチのサイズです。画面に合わせるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

画面全体で良いのなら、

```
subView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubView:subView];
```

で大丈夫だと思います。
subView内のコンテンツはAutoLayoutを設定しておけば、見た目も崩れないと思います。